# Can we update the system tables provided in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

The tables with table names sys. , can we update these tables?

Updating any schema for those tables or updating values in the table?

Comment: You don't want to modify those tables.  They are what makes the database work.

Comment: You can update values.  For example, renaming a column will update a record in one of those tables.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally not because they should be set by using appropriate stored procedures. You should not try to outsmart `SQL Server`.

Back to `SQL Server 2000` you could use [allow updates Option](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196704%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

> **Use the allow updates option to specify whether direct updates can be
>   made to system tables. By default, allow updates is disabled (set to
>   0), so users cannot update system tables through ad hoc updates. Users
>   can update system tables using system stored procedures only.** When
>   allow updates is disabled, updates are not allowed, even if you have
>   the appropriate permissions (assigned using the GRANT statement).
>
> When allow updates is enabled (set to 1), any user who has appropriate
>   permissions can update system tables directly with ad hoc updates and
>   can create stored procedures that update system tables.

From `SQL Server 2008` it is obsolete to [allow updates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179262.aspx):

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Do not use this feature in new development work, and modify
>   applications that currently use this feature as soon as possible.
>
> Changing the allow updates option will cause the RECONFIGURE statement
>   to fail. Changes to the allow updates option should be removed from
>   all scripts.

**The key point why it was disabled is very simply. If you mess up badly with metadata you can prevent an instance of `SQL Server` from running or can cause data loss.**

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot update anything like sys.objects or sys tables, etc. And they aren't even tables to begin with: they are actually Views.

Being able to directly UPDATE  system metadata ended with the release of SQL Server 2005, which is when all of the metadata access switched to being Views.